# Lightning Component Links

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx

How to learn lightning component to easy way in salesforce.
Please give me best links for learning  lightning component links and best way for learn lightning component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Go through trail head basics:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics

and also book mark these site:

http://sfdcmonkey.com/

and also so many you tube videos are available for Lightning go through it,

Comment: Than your very much for your   response  With data.